# 2 Column Layout - Main Link Display

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a basic HTML page with a 2 column layout.  I created a menu page on the sidebar column and when a link is chosen from the menu I want to display it in the main section of the index.html page.  I tried doing this with iframes but its basically creating a duplicate of the index page.  Help!

I guess I can't post a picture because I'm new to this but I basically have an index page and then a farm with a duplicate of my index page.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order for us to resolve your problems, it would be very helpful if you post a reproducible case. What you have posted is a mere description of your problem. I would encourage you to post some code (not necessarily your production code but a reduced version of it which recreates your problem).

Comment: looking like this example? http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/8jNn4/